# django 1.7 run the faked migration for real

Tags: django, django-migrations

I mistakenly faked the latest migration file 0081. how can I run it for real?

do I just need?

```
python manage.py migrate myapp 0081
```

Comment: I guess you could just migrate to the previous one `python manage.py migrate myapp 0080` and then migrate again to `0081` without the `--fake` flag

Answer (score 1):

I just did:

```
python manage.py migrate myapp 0080 --fake
python manage.py migrate myapp
```

actually simple logic ;)

Comment: Why would you fake the migration before 0081? That was executed already. I'm in the same position, faked 0081, but now I want to execute it for real. Your solution doesn't seem right